# ¿Cómo hago para que mi app desarrollada con react native me permita compartir fotos en facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, react-native

No necesito hacer el login con facebook ni nada de eso, lo que necesito es ligar mi app con facebook para que me de permisos de publicar fotos cuando yo quiera.
Ya he creado mi app en facebook-developer, ahora solo necesito el codigo para proceder a pedir los permisos y compartir la imagen desde la app, usando react native.

Les agradecería la ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo hice lo que tu quieres con Appcelerator siguiendo la documentación del siguiente  enlace, que te dirige a facebook developers. 
Debes registrarte y crear una aplicación en facebook para aplicarla a la tuya.
Espero te sea de ayuda, un saludo.
[facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing)

Comment: ¿Lo hiciste con react native?

Comment: Como te dige, la hice con Appcelerator. Pero imagino sera igual.
En la documentación de Facebook for developers encontraras los detalles, teniendo en cuenta que react native esta creada por facebook, no creo que tengas problemas pues para compartir con las aplicaiones creadas con cualquier plataforma, tendrás que crear la app de facebook. 
Un saludo y perdona por tardar en responder.                                            https://developers.facebook.com/products/sharing/

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ahí pude encontrar la documentación necesario, un saludo.